# Normality Test for a Random Sample on SPSS

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption

I have created a random sample of 100 values in SPSS and need to now test for normality with an appropriate goodness of fit test.

I am trying to do a One-Sample t-test via Analyze -> Compare Means -> One Sample T Test and I get a t-statistic of 47.584 and p-value of 0.000. Is this the appropriate test to use? Is there another test that can be done on SPSS that will give better results?

Comment: 1. A t-test is not a test of normality. 2. Why are you testing normality? (And why *have to*? How does the compulsion arise?)

Comment: Thank you - this is for a question that I need to answer for a course. I had a feeling what I was doing wasn't right. We had to make a random sample of 100 values and then the question says: test the data for normality using an appropriate goodness of fit test.

Comment: Could possibly the Shapiro-Wilk test be appropriate (doing Analyze -> Descriptive Statistics -> Explore on SPSS)?

Comment: That's an appropriate test of normality, yes. Indeed, I'd have suggested that given the context in your prior comment. I guess I'll turn that into an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirmation, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A t-test is not a test of normality. (It's used to test equality of two population means or of one population mean with a hypothesized mean.)

You need a goodness of fit test; a widely used test with good power is the [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) test. It can be found in most stats packages (including SPSS).